# Finding maximum value of function when $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ is too complex to solve.

Tags: calculus, optimization

I came across this question regarding the maximum of the Lemur population.

[image]

We are supposed to do this without the use of any graphing software. 
I have differentiated the function but it still remains too complex to be solved.

This is what I got.

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=(x^2-7x+4)\cos(\frac{\pi x}{4})\frac{\pi}{4}+\sin(\frac{\pi x}{4})(2x-7)$$

My thought process was that within the interval $[0,2]$, $2x-7<0, \sin(\frac{\pi x}{4})>0, \cos(\frac{\pi x}{4})>0.$ The roots of $x^2-7x+4$ within the interval is $\frac{7-\sqrt{33}}{2}$. $\frac{dy}{dx}>0$ initally, but then at some value before $\frac{7-\sqrt{33}}{2}$, $\frac{dy}{dx}<0$, which means that the function is strictly decreasing afterwards. To find the minimum, one has to just plug in the extreme values to find $f(0)=20, f(2)=14$, so the minimum occurs when $x=2$.

I realise the same reasoning does not apply to find the maximum. Desmos says that the maximum occurs $0.303 \neq \frac{7-\sqrt{33}}{2}$. If I equate $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$, then I get that $x$ must satisfy this equation:

$$\tan(\frac{\pi x}{4})=\frac{\pi}{4}[\frac{x^2-7x+4}{7-2x}]$$

Which doesn't seem solvable by hand.

I've taught about the hint the question gave, but I don't have any ideas. Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: Your analysis looks good so far. Note that $\sqrt{33} $ is a little smaller than $6$, so you showed that the derivative is negative for $x > 0.5$. At $x=0$ the derivative is equal to $4$, so it does have a zero somewhere in between, which is consistent with the answer of $0.303$ but I agree that the exact location doesn't seem solvable by hand.

Comment: Alright, I agree it's not solvable by hand too. I will answer my own question when I find out how to do it from my professor.

Comment: Alright, it is a printing error on the page. It should have been $x^2-7x-4$